# What IAM policy do I need to sign an browser-based POST policy document?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My goal is to make a browser only upload form into an S3 bucket. I'm following the instructions here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTExamples.html

In it, one needs to create a policy document and then sign it using the secret access key. If I follow the instructions exactly, using my administrator-level account (e.g. access to all the things), everything works.

I would prefer to have a user account *specific* for this function and sign the document using that user's credentials. This way, I can easily deprecate the key (or entire user) whenever I wish. However, it is not listed in the instructions (nor can I figure out from google/experimentation) precisely **what authority this user needs in IAM in order to sign the document**. I've even tried being as wide as the policy below (I renamed bucket name to my-bucket), which is sufficient for the user to log into S3's web interface and manage the bucket entirely from there. However, using the upload form still yields access denied. Please note that my desired behavior is to allow this user *only* to upload files to a specific folder in a specific bucket. Not delete, get, etc.

```
{
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: *"Each form field that you specify in the form (except AWSAccessKeyId, signature, file, policy, and field names that have an x-ignore- prefix) must be included in the list of conditions"* (in the policy document that's included in the form).  Are there any fields in your form that aren't in the policy document you're generating?

Comment: No, I believe its kosher. If I sign the policy doc using the key and secret of an admin user, it works. I just want to create a user who only has access to sign this document.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but when I was reading this question to find the answer I tried it again and it works with your policy, I was trying several times before but didn't work. Here is my info: The uploads I'm working with are to cloudfront, so I think the cache was the problem, after changing the policy with the one you use, I invalidate my distribution and It works for me, I hope you solved your problem!!

Comment: Can you clarify how you cleared the cache so future readers who stumble upon this post might find value in your answer?

Comment: Sure, I used the poicy of question, but after getting not allowed error from cloudfront I create an Invalidation to the distribution in Cloudfront->Invalidations with a wildcard(*) and It works, I don know if profesor_tortuga was using cloudfront but I think this could help for future references, Also I noticed something else: If you are using angular-fullstack on dev environment be sure after you change the secret key and key id deploy again your server (gulp serve) just to be sure the whole changes have been saved (in case the secret key is on server and key id is on client)